# InputAccessoryView of a UITextField

Tags: uitextfield

I need to stick a toolBar with a UITextField inside to a keyboard.

What if I make the whole toolBar (which I think is the textField's super view) the inputAccessoryView of its textField?

I mean like this:

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;  // textField is inside the toolBar

I've been trying on this but I have not made it work yet.

Anyone can help?

Or is there another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you setting the property?  You may be setting it after the view has already loaded.

Try setting it in

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
        [self createAccessoryView];

        [textField setDelegate:self];
        [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
        [textField setInputAccessoryView:fieldAccessoryView];


      }


- (void)createAccessoryView
        {

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
            fieldAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            fieldAccessoryView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
            fieldAccessoryView.tag = 200;

            [fieldAccessoryView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

            UIBarButtonItem *spaceButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
            UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone  target:self action:@selector(done:)];

            UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Previous", @""), NSLocalizedString(@"Next", @""), nil]];
            [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
            [segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
            UIBarButtonItem *segmentButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

            [fieldAccessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentButton, spaceButton, doneButton, nil] animated:NO];
            [segmentButton release];
            [spaceButton release];
            [doneButton release];
            [segmentedControl release];

        }
```